# When attempting to redirect website to another html page states that html document I am linking to is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, authentication, redirect

My goal here is to redirect the website, currently just on localhost activated by node through command prompt, to a different html document when there is a successful login attempt.

Error I am having is:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

This occurs when the line of code shown underneath is activated.

Attempts I have mode to remedy error is primarily focused around altering the link to the html document found here:

`global.location.replace(path.join(__dirname, + '/static/test.html'));`

Full code is:

```
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

// http://localhost:3000/
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    // Render login template
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
});

// http://localhost:3000/auth
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    // Capture the input fields
    let username = request.body.username;
    let password = request.body.password;
    // Ensure the input fields exists and are not empty
    if (username && password) {
        // Execute SQL query that'll select the account from the database based on the specified username and password
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            // If there is an issue with the query, output the error
            if (error) throw error;
            // If the account exists
            if (results.length > 0) {
                // Authenticate the user
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                // Redirect to home page
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});

// http://localhost:3000/home
app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    // If the user is loggedin
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        // Output html
        global.location.replace(path.join(__dirname, + '/static/test.html'));
    } else {
        // Not logged in
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

File structure is with the js and login.html file in the same folder and test.html file in a folder, static, within the folder which the other two files are in.

Comment: `location` has no meaning in Node. It's only available in a browser.

Comment: Anything I can use in node which would have the same effect?

Comment: You probably want something like [redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)